# Deserialize JSON string with variable number of elements

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am receiving a third party API JSON response through Javascript, which I AJAX send to the server. Here I am trying to convert this into an object. I've seen some simple example of this online using a custom class, but the problem in my case is that the number of fields can change. In one case they may just be: UserName: Blah, Age: Blah...In another case it may be: UserName: Blah, Age: Blah, Favourite game: Blah.

What is the best solution here?

Thank you for any input.

PS: I am trying this code below, but I get error: Friends is not supported for deserialization of an array.

```
public class Friends 
{
    public IList<IDictionary<string,string>>data {get;set;}
}

protected void UpdateTrigger_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Friends fbFriends = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Friends>(Hidden1.Value);
}
```

Comment: If the fields are not defined in advance, why convert it to a strongly-typed object, since you won't know the member names?

Comment: The fields will be known in advance, however they will vary.

Comment: Then why not have one big class which contains all possible members, and always deserialize into on object of that type? The missing properties will just be null.

Comment: Yes, I am considering that option, but in my case it's a lot of members 1-20 or so, was trying to find an easier way.

Comment: I managed to get this to work, first of all I need to put by JSON in a container such that ASP.NET receives the usual d.myJSONobject. Second, the 'data' in Friends class needs to be renamed to 'd,' then everything works.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) - you can deserialise into a custom .NET object that exposes all the properties and do `if (thing.Property != null)` to get the specific values, or you could deserialise to `dynamic`.

Comment: That does looks like a great option. Unfortunately, my company hosts the development environment on a high security server with no access to internet so I cannot install third party dlls. Any alternatives?

Comment: JSON.NET is included in the out-of-the-box ASP.NET world now, so I'd say you can consider it safe, and not worry about it being some rogue third-party library.

Comment: As @JoeEnos mentioned, json.net is included in the ASP.NET project templates for visual studio so if you're using VS2012 you will probably have it anyway (may not be the latest version). Failing that, can you ask them to make a copy of it available (download on another server and transfer) I understand the need for security but it shouldn't prevent you using 3rd party frameworks which make your life easier - especially if they're open source and recommended by Microsoft themselves.